# Is the Java program containing native code of C language Machine dependent?

Tags: java, jvm

Java Supports Native Language Code , Does this mean that i can Execute a C language Code Using the java program . If yes then will this be a machine dependent code or Machine independent code and as JVM applied many security related restrictions on the java code so will they effect the code that is in C Language ?
Will The Restrictions applied By JVM be applicable on the Native C language code also ?

Comment: Strictly speaking C is traditionally implemented as a compiled language; it can't be executed directly. What you can execute is the compiled code generated *from C code*. Such compiled code is *architecture* and *platform* dependent, that is it can only run on a CPU of suitable arcitecture running a suitable OS platform.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, the project will be machine-dependent. If the native library/code cannot be *linked to* by that JVM (for example, if you have a Windows JVM and an ELF/.so library, or a 32-bit JVM and 64-bit library), then `System.loadLibrary(String)` will fail with an `UnsatisfiedLinkError`.